# Remove categories in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to remove some categories.

```
account.DeliveryStore.Categories.Remove(n);
```

I try remove by index, CategoryID or name, but it very rarely works. (3 or 4 try)
No errors, no exceptions, nothing. It just ignoring that command.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get a single instance of the Categories class:

```
 Outlook.Categories categories = account.DeliveryStore.Categories;
```

And then you can deal with the `categories` object.

Be aware, the number of items is decreased when the category is removed from the list. So, by calling the [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867529(v=office.15).aspx) method you get the number of items decreased. You may run into the out of bounds exception if try to increase the index after.

Also I'd recommend releasing underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but it works:

account.DeliveryStore.**Session**.Categories.Remove(n);